# Prevent JsonTextReader from consuming the stream during deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Json.Net to consume some seekable streams.

```
// reset the input stream, in case it was previously read
inputStream.Position = 0;
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
{
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
    {
        deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader, expectedType);
    }
}
```

However, this method 'consumes' the stream, meaning the first contained valid Json token is removed from the stream.

That it very annoying. And meaningless, stream Position is provided to emulate a consumption, and 'reading' generally implies 'not modifying'.

Of course, I can dump the stream into a MemoryStream to protect my precious source stream, but that's a huge overhead, especially when doing trial-and-error on a deserialization.

If there is a way to to just 'read' and not 'read-and-consume', thanks for your help, I could not find documentation about that (and I hope this post will help others to google the solution ^^).

Answer (score 2):

[`JsonTextReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) is a *forward-only* reader, meaning it cannot be set back to a position earlier in the JSON to re-read a portion of it, even if the underlying stream supports seeking.  However, the reader does not actually "consume" the stream, as you said.  If you set the `CloseInput` property on the reader to `false` to prevent it from closing the underlying reader and stream when it is disposed, you can position the stream back to the beginning and open a new reader on the same stream to re-read the JSON.  Here is a short program to demonstrate reading the same stream twice:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{ ""name"": ""foo"", ""size"": ""10"" }";
        MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                inputStream.Position = 0;

                using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
                {
                    reader.CloseInput = false;

                    Widget w = serializer.Deserialize<Widget>(reader);

                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + w.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Size: " + w.Size);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Widget
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: foo
Size: 10

Name: foo
Size: 10
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fftZV7

Answer (score 0):

A stream may be consumed once read. The solution could be to copy it to a memory or file stream as below:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
inputStream.CopyTo(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(ms))
(...)
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: The OP specifically said in the question that he did not want to copy the stream due to high overhead.